# I need to write window.onload=function() for Javascript to work

Tags: javascript, function, window, onload

I've been suffering from a ridiculous problem. I need to write

```
window.onload=function(){ 
//Javascript Code
 }
```

to make the javascript work.

For instance my following code doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>JS test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
      var hours;
      var minutes;
      var seconds;
      var temp;

      function countdown() {
      seconds = document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML;
      splitt = seconds.split(":");
      hours = parseInt(splitt[0], 10);
      minutes = parseInt(splitt[1], 10);
      seconds = parseInt(splitt[2], 10);

      if (hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
      temp = document.getElementById('countdown');
      temp.innerHTML = "all done, bye bye";
      return;
      }

      if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
      hours--;
      minutes=60;
      }
      if (seconds == 0) {
      minutes--;
      seconds=60;
      } 
      seconds--;
      temp = document.getElementById('countdown');
      temp.innerHTML = hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
      timeoutMyOswego = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
      } 

      countdown();
      </script></head>

  <body>

      <div id="countdown">
        47:3:24
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**but this one does:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>JS test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

window.onload=function(){
var hours;
      var minutes;
      var seconds;
      var temp;

      function countdown() {
      seconds = document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML;
      splitt = seconds.split(":");
      hours = parseInt(splitt[0], 10);
      minutes = parseInt(splitt[1], 10);
      seconds = parseInt(splitt[2], 10);

      if (hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
      temp = document.getElementById('countdown');
      temp.innerHTML = "all done, bye bye";
      return;
      }

      if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
      hours--;
      minutes=60;
      }
      if (seconds == 0) {
      minutes--;
      seconds=60;
      } 
      seconds--;
      temp = document.getElementById('countdown');
      temp.innerHTML = hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
      timeoutMyOswego = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
      } 

      countdown();
}


      </script></head>

  <body>

      <div id="countdown">
        47:3:24
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm unable to figure out why is it so happening and why i need to write window.onload=function() for my javascript to work everytime?

ThankYou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
seconds = document.getElementById('countdown')
```

You can't get an element from the DOM before you put the element in the DOM.

The script runs before the body is loaded.

Nothing that is added to the DOM in the body will be available to the script.

Running the script when the document has finished loading avoids that issue.